# How make pwd return remote personal working directory

Tags: ssh, pwd

`pwd` over ssh returns the local personal working directory. How can I easily access the remote pwd?

## edit

I use ssh-agent forwarding 1x:
local -> server1 -> server2 there I want to execute these scripts https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html e.g. `authority=${PWD}/ssl/ca.pem` but instead of the remote working directory my local directory from the local computer is used.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how you've tried running ssh to get the pwd ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
ssh host echo $PWD
```

the `$PWD` variable is evaluated in **your** shell and not in the remote. If you want to evaluate the variable remote, you need tu escape the `$` sign:

```
ssh host echo \$PWD
```

or put the command into single quotes:

```
ssh host 'echo $PWD'
```